# Как установить sharpGL для VisualStudio 2019 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharpgl

Я пытаюсь установить расширение sharpGL для visual stuio. Пишет что невозможно установить расширение не для одного пакета.
Сами логи: https://pastebin.com/KB2D23gh

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DWMKerr.SharpGL-12098&ssr=false#overview читайте что там написано

Comment: А есть альтернативы sharpGL?

Comment: Просто установите нагет пакет в проект: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpGL